# Node.js set extension of file being served

Tags: node.js, mime-types, file-extension

On my Node.js server, I have a route that requests data from the database, and converts it from JSON to CSV.

I then state the content type is application/csv, and serve the file.

```
var csvBlob = json2csv(jsonBlob);
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/csv' });
res.end(csvBlob);
```

When I get the file on my client side, it just comes out as 'filename', with no file extension. How do I serve the file with the extension?

#### Note:

My client doesn't necessarily send accept headers asking for CSV, as the request can be called as a simple browser URL, such as:

```
http://myserver.org/resources/mydbquery/xls
http://myserver.org/resources/mydbquery/csv
http://myserver.org/resources/mydbquery/pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
    , 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=download.csv'
});
```

Comment: Thanks I happened to just have tried that - it works if you copy the URL of the request and run it in the browser, however if i do an XHR GET request, it returns successfully, but with no response body and the user is not prompted with the download...

Comment: Instead of doing a XHR request, try redirecting the user (a simple `window.location = '/resources/mydbquery/csv'` should do it). The browser should notice it's a download, and the user will not leave the current page. They will, however, be prompted to download the file.